# Is there any combination of camera, GPS and software which support the GPSDestXYZ exif tags?

Tags: software, metadata, geotagging

As [Patrick Kowalzick pointed out](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11688/should-i-geotag-the-location-of-the-subject-or-the-photographer/11717#11717) in a [previous discussion](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11688/should-i-geotag-the-location-of-the-subject-or-the-photographer), the [EXIF standards](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-1.PDF?page=62) since 1998 have included tags to document the `destination point` of a photograph.  Tags include `GPSDestLatitude`, `GPSDestLongitude`, `GPSDestBearing`, and `GPSDestDistance`.

Is there any camera, GPS or software (or combination of the above) which support the GPSDestXYZ exif tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solmeta sells two Geotaggers supporting orientation:
http://www.solmeta.com/dede/pro.html

- Geotagger Pro: 3 axis electronic
  compass, output heading
- Geotagger
  N2: 2 axis electronic compass, output
  heading

Some cameras have built in compass as well:

- Panasonic Lumix DMC-FT3
- Sony Cybershot DSC-HX5V / HX7V / HX100V
- RICOH G700SE
- Sony Alpha SLT-A55
- Casio Exilim H20G (Hybrid GPS - Trackins indoor movements using accelerometer and compass)

I think for GPSDestLatitude, GPSDestLongitude and GPSDistance there is some software and manual processing necessary.

Comment: Do you have any details on what software supports manual processing?

Comment: @fmark: No, I don't. But it seems geosetter supports it:

http://www.geosetter.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/v330_02_map_add_heading2_en.jpg

Comment: Wow, hadn't seen geosetter before, it looks great :)

Answer (score 2):

First off, a reminder: The IPTC spec clearly distinguishes "Location Created" (position of the photographer) vs "Location Shown" (main subject seen in image).

No camera or GPS unit can set these GPSDestXYZ EXIF tags. They are about a subjective concept. You need software in post-processing to tell what is the "Location Shown". I don't know any software that supports this.

Unfortunately, the EXIF spec does not clearly specify what "destination" means in these GPS IFD tags 19-26. The Metadata Working Group recommends using them for "Location Shown". Reference: Section "5.8 Location" of "[Guidelines For Handling Image Metadata](http://www.metadataworkinggroup.org/pdf/mwg_guidance.pdf)" Version 2.0 from November 2010.

A digital compass is useful to set `GPSImgDirection`. A GPS unit is useful to set "Location Created" coordinates, and `GPSTrack` if the photographer is moving. "Location Shown" and therefore the GPSDestXYZ tags can't be determined automatically.